# Barcode Scanner using Ionic/ngcordova, not getting data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, barcode, ngcordova

I've got a controller:

```
.controller('BarCodeScanCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

    $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(barcodeData) {
            // Success! Barcode data is here
            console.log(barcodeData.text);
            alert('barcode scanned:' + barcodeData);

        }, function(error) {
            alert('Error');
            console.log(error);
            // An error occurred
        });

    };
});
```

I'm using the QR code generator: http://www.qr-code-generator.com/ but I can't seem to retrieve any of the data I'm inputting. It's returning the `barCode` object the values of `text` & `format` properties are empty. The `cancel` property is `true`.

```
{
  "cancelled": true,
  "text":"",
  "format": ""
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have uploaded a working sample in [github](https://github.com/Sabharshin/ionic_qr_code_scanner), please have a look.

Steps:

1) Create a project 
 2) cd into the project 
3) Add required platforms
    4) Add ngcordova-min.js file to the js folder 
5) Add the ngcordova
    js file path in index.html just before cordova path 
6) Add ngcordova
    dependancy to app.js 
7) Add plugin 
8) Add the function in html page
    
9) Add the logic in controller 
10) Test the app

Comment: Yes, I've got it working in my app but the .text, .format attributes are empty with whatever QR code I scan.

Comment: Kindly look into the log the below line will give the imageData object (text, format)
console.log(imageData);

Comment: Yes it comes out as {object Object}.  {{barcodeData}} returns ("cancelled": true, "text":"". "format": ""}.

Comment: The issue is that text and format are empty no matter what code I scan so it seems that it is not working properly.

Comment: It seems the event is getting cancelled ('Cancelled' : true), it should give 'false' on success, the attached github project on scanning of this sample image http://qrcode.meetheed.com/images/qr_code_cal.png gives the correct result. Please check

Comment: Ahh, I see. Can you link me to the more detailed steps procedure that you followed?

Comment: I have followed Nic Raboy's blog https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: I have followed the instructions and rerun the app however I still get cancellation = true. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, may be you can ask Nic Raboy in blog post comment section, he usually replies fast.

Comment: Similar issue has been posted in this [link](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/286), have you tested with the github project, was it returning the correct object.

Comment: Have also found this [Old Issue](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/180) related to version

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are using Ionic. You should use on-touch directive from ionic not ng-click, because somehow when you are using ng-click it triggered the scan view twice and cause a force quit (CMIIW).

use it like this in your views:

```
<button on-touch="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

If the cancel property is true you stop the scanning function manually.

inject `$ionicPlatform` in your controller

```
.controller('BarCodeScanCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $ionicPlatform) {
  $scope.scanQR = function () {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan()
      .then(function(barcodeData) {
        alert('result = '+barcodeData.text);
        alert('type = '+barcodeData.format);
        alert('cancelled = '+barcodeData.cancelled);
      }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
      });
    });
  }
});
```